# transition no funciona en local

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy creando una web pero sucede que necesito añadir transitions pero no me funcionan, no entiendo que pasa, si de pronto es porque la estoy programando en mi pc, o hay otra forma de hacerlo.

```css
    #ftn{
    width: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    height: 100px;
    -webkit-transition: width 1s;
    transition: width 1s;
  
    /* Tambien probe con */
    -webkit-transition: width 2s ease;
    -moz-transition: width 2s ease;
    -ms-transition: width 2s ease;
    -o-transition: width 2s ease;
    transition: width 2s ease;
    }
```

```html
<div id='ftn'>
    <h1>hola</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Tienes que definir cuando quieres que haga la animación, asociarla a un evento como pasar el ratón por encima o pulsar un botón. Si quieres que se ejecute directamente entonces deberias usar `animation` en lugar de `transition`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation

Comment: y cómo hago para que se active la animación pero al dar click?

Comment: Con javascript. Haces una clase con la propiedad  que quieres animar y el nuevo valor que debe tener y se la añades con javascript. Igual que el ejemplo de la respuesta de @IvanIsayenko pero usando una clase en lugar de `:hover`

Answer (score 1):

```css
#ftn{
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: width 1s;
  transition: width 1s;
}

#ftn:hover{
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id='ftn'>
  <h1>hola</h1>
</div>
```

Buenas. Tu código no esta mal, lo único que te falta por poner es lo que quieres que haga. En todos los casos te pongo un ejemplo de como seria con un `hover` y como hace la animación fluida.

Espero que te sirva